# Filtrar una columna como FACTOR?

Tags: r

Me he topado con un problema un poco gordo para mi corta experiencia en el mundo de R. Espero poder contar con la ayuda de alguno de ustedes.

Estoy trabajando con data de este tipo

```
> head(b0s95w)
  b0s95w.date b0s95w.SST
1    20140617      25.00
2    20140622      25.13
3    20140627      24.53
4    20140702      24.85
5    20140707      24.55
6    20140712      23.99
```

Lo que tengo aquí son fechas y temperaturas superficiales del agua en una ubicación determinada del océano pacífico. El problema viene cuando quiero filtrar las temperaturas de una determinada fecha, los valores en mi dataframe son factores y no me funciona subset ni dplyr.

```
> str(b0s95w)
'data.frame':   190 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ b0s95w.date: Factor w/ 190 levels "20140617","20140622",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ b0s95w.SST : Factor w/ 168 levels "-9.99","18.50",..: 122 125 113 121 114 104 117 96 86 32 ...
```

Ejemplo:

```
#Usando subset------------------------------------------
jun2014<-subset(b0s95w, b0s95w$b0s95w.date>="20140601" & b0s95w.date<="20140631")
Warning messages:
1: In Ops.factor(b0s95w$b0s95w.date, "20140601") :
  ‘>=’ not meaningful for factors
2: In Ops.factor(b0s95w.date, "20140631") :
  ‘<=’ not meaningful for factors

#Usando dplyr-------------------------------------------
b0s95w %>% filter(b0s95w.date>="20140601" & b0s95w.date<="20140630")
[1] b0s95w.date b0s95w.SST 
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
Warning messages:
1: In Ops.factor(b0s95w.date, "20140601") :
  ‘>=’ not meaningful for factors
2: In Ops.factor(b0s95w.date, "20140630") :
  ‘<=’ not meaningful for factors
```

Comment: Diego, de donde obtienes estos datos? ¿los lees de un archivo? ¿Con que función? te lo pregunto por que las rutinas base de R tienen la mala costumbre de convertir caracteres en factores, y que un número como la temperatura este como factor, parece indicar que lo interpretó como caracter, lo cual es una señal que el archivo no fue leído de la manera óptima.

Answer (score 1):

bienvenido.

El problema se da porque estás intentando evaluar magnitud (con `>= <=`) en un vector de la clase factor. Los factores se utilizan para datos categóricos (variables nominales), en los que no tendría sentido pensar en un orden. Es decir, no tienen el atributo que estás tratando de evaluar.

> Hay factores ordenados de la clase `ordered` con los es posible usar los operadores `>` y `<`, pero no son buena idea en este caso.

En tu caso los factores problemáticos son fechas, así lo mejor sería trabajarlas como tales, es decir, recodificar tu variable a la clase `Date`. Hay varias formas de hacerlo, el paquete `lubridate::` tiene funciones con una interfaz simple y consistente para manejar fechas y se lleva muy bien con `dplyr::`.

## Solución

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

b0s95w <- data.frame (b0s95w.date = c("20140617", "20140622", "20140627", "20140702", "20140707", "20140712"), 
            b0s95w.SST = c(25.00, 25.13, 24.53, 24.85, 24.55, 23.99), 
            stringsAsFactors = TRUE) #Valor por defecto

b0s95w %>% 
  # Paso a fecha, ymd pasa silenciosamente el factor a character
  mutate(b0s95w.date = ymd(b0s95w.date)) %>%                              
  # Las condiciones deben ser fechas, en este caso el output de ymd()     
  filter(b0s95w.date >= ymd("20140622") & b0s95w.date <= ymd("20140630"))
```

La función importante es `ymd()`: año, mes día. Recibe una cadena de caracteres o un vector coercionable a `character` con una representación literal de una fecha en formato año-mes-día y la convierte en una fecha válida, con atributos numéricos que permiten ordenar, filtrar, calcular diferencias, etc.

Si lees inglés `lubridate::` tiene un viñeta muy práctica para aprender a hacer cosas con fechas.

Lo de fechas *válidas* es importante, en tu ejemplo buscabas filtrar por el 2014-06-31, fecha que nunca existió porque junio tiene 30 días. Ese tipo de errores frecuentes se solucionan usando fechas de manera explícita: si paso algo así la funciones de `lubridate::` pasan un error o emiten una advertencia.